# Can't let other people edit code from github with eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, github, egit

I made my own repository on GitHub, I can edit it from Eclipse, but when I share it with other users they can't `push` to Upstream.

How can I grant them permission to edit the code? Also added them to Collaborators tab this doesn't help.

They get `error git-receive-park not permitted`

Thanks.

Comment: Have them fork your repository and submit pull requests.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this doesn't have anything to do with the IDE **you** are using. Because that is only about **your** access to the repository.

Thus: step back, and understand the *workflow* to use when working with github. See [here](https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/) for example:

> Open a Pull Request
>
> Pull Requests initiate discussion about your commits.

That is what you are looking for!